# I have a date and time value in a cell and i want to make the seconds as 00, how do i do it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell value, for example
A1 = 17/06/2016 19:00:46
i want to change it to 17/06/2016 19:00:00
so basically the seconds have to be 0 but i can not seem to be able to achieve that with the formatting. I did the format as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm, but the seconds is still retaining.
i will be using these values to match the values in a different sheet using Application.Match in vba. the different sheet has the seconds as 0, hence, to match it i need to be convert these to 0 seconds.
Thank you.

Comment: format is for display-only. it doesn't change the value stored in the field, it only changes what you see on-screen. you need to actually  modify the underlying value.

Comment: how can i do that to the value? maybe the round the seconds up or down? No idea. thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way to achieve this:

```
Function DateWithZeroSeconds(MyDate As Date)
DateWithZeroSeconds = Format(MyDate, "dd/mm/yyyy h:m") & ":00"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you wish to convert and run this short macro:

```
Sub SecondKiller()
    Dim d As Date, d2 As Date
    For Each r In Selection
        d = r.Value
        r.Value = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), Day(d)) + TimeSerial(Hour(d), Minute(d), 0)
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. it does work but i found sgdva's solution more simpler to use match with.

Answer (score 0):

An other way, format the Excel cell, and then show the seconds as 00's:

```
Sub FormatRange_AsDate(ByVal Rg As Range)
With Rg
    .NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy h:mm:ss;@" 'give the format to the cell , showing seconds
    .Value = Format(.Value, "d/m/yyyy h:m") & ":00" 'changing the seconds to "00", don't use .value2
End With
End Sub
```